# Why does my mouse's scroll wheel stop working after resuming from suspend in Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, mouse, suspend

I am running Xubuntu 18.04 kernel version 5.0.0-23-generic and using a cheap microsoft usb mouse. I also have setup imwheel with the following settings:

".*"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5

as per this tutorial for slow scroll speed:
http://www.webupd8.org/2015/12/how-to-change-mouse-scroll-wheel-speed.html

**My problem**:

*when I resume from suspend the scroll wheel no longer works*.

A tedious workaround I found is to unplug and replugin the usb receiver. This will bring the scrolling function back, but will not resume the imwheel settings above--the scroll speed is super slow. To get back my scroll speed settings I have to type in console: `imwheel --kill` to restart my imwheel settings.

*Is there anyway to automate this process?* My goal is to have normal scrolling when resuming from suspend without having to go thru steps above.

I am still very new to linux so any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: prior to removing and replacing receiver, Chrome will scroll albeit extreeeemely slowly, but other programs, such as Thunderbird will not scroll at all.

Comment: Your mouse seems to need to have `imwheel` run again, as it looks like `suspend/resume` didn't save/restore its state. Read `man pm-action` (Provided by: `pm-utils_1.4.1-17_all`) to see how to add your command to be run at the right time.

Comment: So, the imwheel --kill command only works after I remove and replace usb receiver.

Answer (score 7):

I know that i'm little bit late. I've came across same issue recently, when i installed a new Microsoft wireless mouse.

Initially I've fixed it by **re-plugging the dongle usb reciever**, but it was really annoying :( .

So i tried something different(which saves my time)

I've **reloaded the usbhid kernel module**

```
#!/bin/bash

#This is the fix for mircosoft mouse scrolling issue after wake from a suspension
if [[ $1 == post ]]; then
    modprobe -r usbhid
    modprobe usbhid
fi
```

Place the above script in following directory

> **/lib/systemd/system-sleep/**

This will do the trick!!

Comment: on which file shall the scribt be saved? what will be the name of the file to be saved, and will it run automatically?

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! That was annoying the as F!

Comment: I have the same problem (https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214). I tried your answer but haven't gotten it to work. It seems to have no effect. I'll also look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309247/48973 Thanks for your answer though. It's a bit encouraging.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem with my Logitech MX Master 3.

First tried removing module `usbhid` or `i2c_hid` but got following error:

```
$ sudo rmmod usbhid
rmmod: ERROR: Module usbhid is in use by: hid_logitech_dj
```

Solution working for me:

```
sudo rmmod hid_logitech_dj
sudo modprobe hid_logitech_dj
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a problem with my Logitech MX Master 3 but for me after resume the scroll would just work intermittently, requiring multiple turns of the scroll wheel to register. Unfortunately just reloading hid_logitech_dj didnt work for me but I noticed another module alongside it: hid_logitech_hidpp and reloading it as well did the trick for me.

Comment: Archlinux `6.4.12-arch1-1` issue solved, thanks